# Icons and Images not showing after published in visual composer

Tags: php, wordpress, visual-composer

[image: screenshot for issue]

I recently make the custom vc element and everything showing perfect except one thing. After select the icon and attach the image all does not show on page. Code is given below please let me know what is the issue and what I am doing wrong in my code. I waiting for your encourage reply. Thanks

```
array(
                    'type' => 'iconpicker',
                    'heading' => __( 'Icon', 'js_composer' ),
                    'param_name' => 'icon_openiconic',
                    'settings' => array(
                    'emptyIcon' => false, // default true, display an "EMPTY" icon?
                    'type' => 'openiconic',
                    'iconsPerPage' => 200, // default 100, how many icons per/page to display
                    ),
                    'dependency' => array(
                    'element' => 'icon_type',
                    'value' => 'openiconic',
                                            ),
                    'description' => __( 'Select icon from library.', 'js_composer' ),
                ),


                array(
                      "type" => "attach_image",
                      "class" => "",
                      "heading" => __( "Field Label", "my-text-domain" ),
                      "param_name" => "image",
                      "value" => '',
                      "description" => __( "Enter description.", "my-text-domain" )
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I copy the folder "vc-open-iconic" from visual composer plugin directory and then import css "@import url("vc-elements/vc-open-iconic/vc_openiconic.min.css");" in my main style sheet.

Icons are showing now.